# Fill transition on SVG not working

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, fill

So, I've embedded an SVG version of the Instagram logo into my account, and I have set rules to allow the `fill` property to transition on `:hover`. However, the transition is refusing to work for this particular icon. I have the exactly same rules set on another SVG icon, this one for Medium. The transition works perfectly on that one, but is stubbornly against working on Instagram. Here's the markup and CSS. My site is built in Craft, so you'll see some `Twig` in here.

```
<a href="{{ social.instagram }}" class="instagram" target="_blank">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="12px" height="12px" viewBox="6 345 512 512" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 6 345 512 512">
    <path class="st0" d="M268 394.5c67.3 0 75.2 0.3 101.8 1.5 24.6 1.1 37.9 5.2 46.8 8.7 11.8 4.6 20.2 10 29 18.8s14.3 17.2 18.8 29c3.4 8.9 7.6 22.2 8.7 46.8 1.2 26.6 1.5 34.5 1.5 101.8s-0.3 75.2-1.5 101.8c-1.1 24.6-5.2 37.9-8.7 46.8 -4.6 11.8-10 20.2-18.8 29s-17.2 14.3-29 18.8c-8.9 3.4-22.2 7.6-46.8 8.7 -26.6 1.2-34.5 1.5-101.8 1.5s-75.2-0.3-101.8-1.5c-24.6-1.1-37.9-5.2-46.8-8.7 -11.8-4.6-20.2-10-29-18.8s-14.3-17.2-18.8-29c-3.4-8.9-7.6-22.2-8.7-46.8 -1.2-26.6-1.5-34.5-1.5-101.8s0.3-75.2 1.5-101.8c1.1-24.6 5.2-37.9 8.7-46.8 4.6-11.8 10-20.2 18.8-29s17.2-14.3 29-18.8c8.9-3.4 22.2-7.6 46.8-8.7C192.8 394.7 200.7 394.5 268 394.5M268 349.1c-68.4 0-77 0.3-103.9 1.5 -26.8 1.2-45.1 5.5-61.1 11.7 -16.6 6.4-30.6 15.1-44.6 29.1S35.8 419.5 29.3 436c-6.2 16-10.5 34.3-11.7 61.2 -1.2 26.8-1.5 35.4-1.5 103.8s0.3 77 1.5 103.9c1.2 26.8 5.5 45.1 11.7 61.2 6.4 16.6 15.1 30.6 29.1 44.6s28.1 22.6 44.6 29.1c16 6.2 34.3 10.5 61.2 11.7s35.4 1.5 103.9 1.5 77-0.3 103.9-1.5c26.8-1.2 45.1-5.5 61.2-11.7 16.6-6.4 30.6-15.1 44.6-29.1s22.6-28.1 29.1-44.6c6.2-16 10.5-34.3 11.7-61.2s1.5-35.4 1.5-103.9 -0.3-77-1.5-103.9c-1.2-26.8-5.5-45.1-11.7-61.2 -6.4-16.6-15.1-30.6-29.1-44.6s-28.1-22.6-44.6-29.1c-16-6.2-34.3-10.5-61.2-11.7C345 349.4 336.4 349.1 268 349.1L268 349.1zM268 471.6c-71.4 0-129.4 57.9-129.4 129.4s58 129.4 129.4 129.4 129.4-58 129.4-129.4S339.4 471.6 268 471.6zM268 685c-46.4 0-84-37.6-84-84s37.6-84 84-84 84 37.6 84 84S314.4 685 268 685z"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="402.5" cy="466.5" r="30.2"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.instagram .st0,
.medium svg path {
    transition: fill .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: fill .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: fill .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: fill .3s ease-in;
}

.instagram .st0 {
    fill: #333;
}

.medium .st0 {
    fill: #d0d2d3;
}

.medium .st1 {
    fill: #a6a8ab;
}

.medium .st2 {
    fill: #808184;
}

.medium .st3 {
    fill: #333;
}

.medium .st4 {
    fill: #939393;
}

.medium .st5 {
    fill: #231f20;
}

.instagram:hover .st0,
.medium:hover path {
    fill: #b29f77;
}
```

[Also, here's where the site lives](http://jessewinton.com). All the code is there. Any help from you ninjas would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: It's working just fine for me in modern versions of Chrome and Safari, i.e. the `#333`-colored bit transitions from that color to `#b29f77`. Are you expecting something else to happen?

Comment: WFM on Firefox too.